# Cannot connect to VirtualBox with Bridged Adapter (Linux Mint 20)

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I have a Linux Mint 20 host machine running VirtualBox with Debian 11 (bullseye). NAT connection works fine, but I need a bridged connection for SSH, as the purpose of the virtual machine is to simulate a remote machine in production. Funny thing is, **bridged connection was working at first, but then a couple days later it stopped working**. **This had already happened with other guest OSes**, such as CentOS and Manjaro. Even though at the time I did not bother to investigate the root of the problem, I guess it is a good clue to what could be going on (DHCP ?)

In the host machine, I am connected with WLAN (wlp2s0), but as far as I understand, it should be listed as a cabled connection `enp0s3` in the guest, right?

What I have tried, to no success:

- Installing "Guest Additions CD" -- not sure it actually worked, I still cannot do birectional clipboard, even though I enabled it
- Changing "adapter type" and "promiscuous mode"
- Changing MAC Address in VirtualBox settings so it matches host's network interface's.
- Creating a bridged network `bridge0` in the host and changing network name in VirtualBox from `wlp2s0` to it (not sure I really understand this process, maybe something went wrong).
- I read through [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264087/ubuntu-cant-connect-to-hosts-internet-connection-using-nat) [possibly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011401/vm-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-via-a-bridged-adapter) [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722512/virtualbox-ubuntu-14-04-bridge-adapter-not-working) questions, but it did not seem to apply to my case, and I could not understand much of what was technically going on.

Some information:

**user@host $ ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:83:89:c5:26:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:83:89:d1:2c:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.14/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 58283sec preferred_lft 58283sec
    inet6 2804:14c:1c2:9309::1002/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 533484sec preferred_lft 533484sec
    inet6 2804:14c:1c2:9309:9c84:d6fb:1aff:c777/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 533485sec preferred_lft 15003sec
    inet6 2804:14c:1c2:9309:c861:79dd:1705:f61a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 565181sec preferred_lft 478781sec
    inet6 fe80::e000:da4:1870:553/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: bridge0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:9e:22:d0:ae:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**user@guest $ ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:83:89:d1:2c:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::9a83:89ff:fed1:2cc9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**user@guest $ lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 10)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

So, I see the guest's `uname` says `-amd64`, so I thought it could be solved by changing the adapter type to PCNET, which is from AMD ([according to link](https://archive.is/jY6c7), though is it?). But then, `Bridge` is listed as Intel. I really don't understand any of this, it has been pretty much trial and error and I would be grateful if somebody could help me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [gvanto's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/756545/1484598) at AskUbuntu StackExchange. He refers to [this blog post](https://archive.md/gUSd1), which solved my problem completely. Basically, you need to set up two network interfaces for the guest, one NAT and another Host-only interface (`vbox0` or the like), then configure a static IP for the guest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).